# What is the name of the formulation where you specify sentence parts

Tags: grammar

Say I have the sentence:

> The cat sat on the mat

What's the name of the formulation:

> The-`DET.` cat-`NOUN.` sat-`VERB.` on-`PREP.` the-`DET.` mat-`NOUN`

Or this example from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navajo_language#Nouns)

> Kin á-ø-sh-łééh

> make-`3.obj-1.subj`-make`.mom.impf`

'I build a house.'

Comment: A gloss? Tagging?

Comment: Nowadays that would be called tagging; you use a tagger to produce lines like that. Sort of like that. Before nowadays, it'd've been called parsing, whereas what we nowadays call parsing would've been called construing. Got all that? The difference is whether it just marks part of speech, like your example, or whether it notices that _the cat_ is a noun phrase and that _sat on the mat_ is a verb phrase and that one is the subject of the other and that they form a sentence.

Comment: I'd call it labeling. All constituents in a clause have two labels, a function label and a category one. Yours are the latter.

Comment: @jlawler I've added a more detailed example

Comment: Your examples are very different (syntactic functions vs morphological analysis). The first one: see jlawler’s comment above. The second one is known as glossing.

Comment: I see. you may want to take a look at https://www.eva.mpg.de/lingua/resources/glossing-rules.php

Comment: You should **not** change the example in a question after comments have been made.

Comment: No, just undo the changes you made. Comments may be temporary, and answers can be deleted too. Please respect the time we freely give to help questioners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two different formulations.

The first is known as [Parts-of-speech Tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging), or if done manually [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Human_languages).

The second is known as 'Glossing', or specifically [interlinear glossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlinear_gloss), witha list of [abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_glossing_abbreviations) and [rules](https://www.eva.mpg.de/lingua/resources/glossing-rules.php).